# Why I removed the conflict file but still not able to git pull from remote?

Tags: git

I have a file `main.js` got conflict. Modified by me and another member.

However, I remove the file on my machine. But still not able to pull.

So what should I do to fix it?

```
➜  js git:(master) ✗ rm main.js
➜  js git:(master) ✗ git pull
error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.
hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.
fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.
```

Comment: Are the changes to `main.js` staged? If so, run `git rm main.js` instead.

Comment: Here's an idea. Fix them up in the work tree, and then use `git add/rm <file>`
as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting a file won't automatically solve conflicts. If you got the conflicts during a pull, you are likely in a merge state. You need to cancel the merge with `git merge --abort`. That will allow you to pull. It will not fix your conflicts either. Based on which state you want, you will have to either use the `-X theirs` option or fix the conflicts manually